# Passing event in Angular 6+

Tags: angular, scroll

I am working with two different components. The main component have a nested component(child component) and a form and the child component have two buttons(button 1 and button 2) and some content.

When I click in button 1(located in child component) I need to scroll to the form(located in main component) and when I click in button 2(located in the own child component) it should scroll down to its own content.

I am trying to access to its own content section using ViewportScroller and scrollToAnchor() and at the same time emit the event of the clicked button 1 from the child component to the main component but this doesn't work.

Here is my code:

**main.component.html**

```html
    <my-child-app (click)="scrollTo(element)"></my-child-app>
      .
      .
      .
    <form id="myForm">...</form>
```

**main.component.ts**

```js
    constructor(private scroll: ViewportScroller) {}
    
    scrollTo(element) {
        element.scroll.scrollToAnchor('myForm');
      }
```

**child.component.html**

```html
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="scrollToMyForm($event)">Go to my form</button>
    <button (click)="scrollToContent()">My content</button>
       .
       .
       .
    <div id="myContent">...</div>
```

**child.component.ts**

```js
    export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
      @Output() myForm: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

      constructor(private scrollTwo: ViewportScroller) { }
    
      scrollToMyForm(event) {
        event.target.myForm.emit(true);
      }
    
      scrollToContent() {
        this.scrollTwo.scrollToAnchor('myContent');
      }
```

When I click in "My content" button it goes perfectly to the content(located in the same component) but when I click in "Go to my form" button I get two errors in console:

```js
    Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
```

and

```js
    Cannot read property 'viewportScroller' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'viewportScroller' of undefined
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event.target` in your components is not pointing to the component where this event was triggered but to the HTML element which triggered the event.

So this obviously won't work.

```js
scrollToMyForm(event) {
    event.target.myForm.emit(true);
}
```

I suppose that what you want to achieve is something like this.

In your child component change the name of emitter to make it a bit more clear. It is a good practice to use verbs in the name of the emitter as they should communicate a desired action e.g

```js
@Output() scrollToForm: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

Then in the child component adjust the method

```js
scrollToMyForm(event) {
    this.scrollToForm.emit(true);
}
```

In the main component adjust the listener in the html template

```html
<my-child-app (scrollToForm)="scrollToForm()"></my-child-app>
```

In main.component.ts adjust the method

```js
// no parameter needed
scrollToForm() {
    this.scroll.scrollToAnchor('myForm');
}
```